# How to develop cross platform mobile application using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cross-platform, mobile-application

May be this is a question when a programmer/developer thinks to start mobile application development. But he is habitual of a particular environment in which he is working from several years. So it would be more comfortable that he can develop mobile app in the same environment what he is using from years.

I am currently working in Asp.Net MVC with C#, Visual Studio 2013 and i like it most. I am working on a large MIS and want to make available my solution to all platforms. As we know mobile devices are the most powerful technology current days.

Please suggest some way that i can work in visual studio and can develop cross platform mobile application that can work on Android, MAC, Windows Mobile and Windows PC/Laptops

I know there is many tools are available, but i need an expert suggestion on this particular scenario. If you provide a solution then please describe how to enable it in visual studio or how to customize current solution for that.

Answer (score 2):

To have .net apps running on mobile platforms other than microsoft, have a look at [xamarin](http://xamarin.com/)

This is the front office for the [mono framework](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)

Comment: Cha-ching! Important to note it's not completely a write once-run everywhere solution. Unless it's changed, there's platform specific code needed for each.

Comment: @BobbyDigital is right. Is there no solution that could be "Code for All platform"  ?

Comment: Divergent standards is marketing strategy. Addressing the question from the top will lead to that fact. To handle a fully portable solution, you'll have to start developing on top of some libraries that are really multi-platform (example for gui's: cairo).

Comment: @BobbyDigital we see Java who promises about write once-run everywhere. Where does Java go today? IMHO, that's a crappy approach and doomed to be failed.

Comment: @LexLi: I don't bother with the holy grails. I started with Xamarin and decided it wasn't for me. There will inevitably be issues or loses in a WORE approach, that is unless all devices were built on the same framework.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's probably old question but you can try Apache Cordova with Visual Studio.

More options described in [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/features/mobile-app-development-vs#)